# Elevation shadow is clipped

Tags: android, xml

I tried to add elevation to my custom button but the result is:

[image]

As you can see the shadow is clipped. I have tried to search in StackOverflow and google and I found similar question but no answers :)

***XML:***

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
   android:layout_width="141dp"
   android:layout_height="45dp"
   android:textAlignment="gravity"
   android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:elevation="4dp" />
```

Here is my custom button styles.

***button.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_disabled" />
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" />
<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_regular" />
<item
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_regular" />
</selector>
```

The style when not pressed.

***button_regular.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient android:angle="-90"
    android:centerX="10"
    android:centerY="10"
    android:endColor="#30bbff"
    android:gradientRadius="10"
    android:startColor="#0081c0"
    android:type="linear"/>
<stroke android:width="5dip" android:color="#ffffff" />
<corners android:radius="20dip"/>
<padding android:left="7dp"
    android:top="7dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Your shadows may be getting clipped by the View's bounds. Try adding padding to the bottom of the button.

If the button sits at the bottom of the parent, the parent ViewGroup may also be clipping the shadow. Make sure the parent has padding and set `android:clipToPadding="false"`on the parent.

Comment: This works if you can afford to add the padding, but in most cases additional padding will look bad. Standard elevation (where clipping isn't applied) can draw shadows over other views, there must be a way to achieve the same result without adding padding..

Comment: @behelit I think you can use android:clipChildren="false" and android:clipToPadding="false" together, to fix all of these issues.

Comment: @androiddeveloper is right, I need *all 3* on the parent (padding, clipChildren=false, clipToPadding=false).

Comment: Make sure the parent has padding, *not* margin else this won't work.

Comment: Time saver, Thanks

Comment: This is really going to let me take my craft to the next level, thanks!

Answer (score 34):

Add `android:clipChildren="false"` and `android:clipToPadding="false"` to button two ancestors `ViewGroup`.

Answer (score 1):

**Complete answer**

**Add these 2 line to the parent view**

> android:clipChildren="false"
>
> android:clipToPadding="false"

EXAMPLE:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
           ... >

        <TextView
         style="@style/TextShadowStyle"
          ....
            />
```

Text Shadow Style:

```
 <style name="TextShadowStyle">
        <item name="android:shadowColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:shadowDx">10</item>
        <item name="android:shadowDy">10</item>
        <item name="android:shadowRadius">5</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this using Compose, the clipping was because my content was inside a scrollable container. So, the fix for me was to make the scroll container take up the full height of the screen so that there was room to show the shadows:

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        // We need to fill the height because adding scrolling
        // causes it to clip the elevation shadows if we don't.
        .fillMaxHeight()
        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
) {
```